# OpenCV: max value is -1 after apply adaptiveThreshold function

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to binarize an RGB image using the adaptiveThreshold method. My code is as follow:

```
public byte[] filter(byte[] buff, int width, int height) {

    Mat img_rgb = new Mat(width, height, CvType.CV_8UC3);
    Mat img_gray = new Mat(width, height, CvType.CV_8U);
    Mat img_bin = new Mat(width, height, CvType.CV_8U);     

    img_rgb.put(0, 0, buff);        
    Imgproc.cvtColor(img_rgb, img_gray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);                
    Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(img_gray, img_bin, 255, 
               Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 5, 2);

    int size = (int) img_bin.total() * img_bin.channels();
    byte[] bin_buff = new byte[size];
    img_bin.get(0, 0, bin_buff);

    return bin_buff;

}
```

The max value of the `img_bin` data after apply the adaptiveThreshold should be 255, but it is -1 instead. Why is this happening? I'm new to OpenCV and i can't find any explanation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two's complement representation of −1 in a signed byte is equal to that of 255 in an unsigned byte.It may be that you are missing a cast somewhere in your code.

Comment: You're right! I forgot to configure the Java Primitives in the debugger, so it was showing the values as signed instead of unsigned...